# What is the correct interpretation of this arrow function subscribing an Observable in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, arrow-functions, angular-observable

I am following the official Angular tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

As you can see there is one component class that subscribe on a service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedHero: Hero;

  heroes: Hero[];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
        .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }
}
```

I have some doubts about the `getHeroes()` method of this component:

```
 getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
        .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }
```

I know that my service returns an `Observable<Hero[]>` that I have to subscribe to because it is asynchronous.

The only thing that I can't completly understand is the inner expression (I think it is called lambda), this: 
`heroes => this.heroes = heroes`

What is the exact meaning of this expression?

Comment: It's an *arrow function*, that's the callback.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, it is indeed a lambda, however they are more commonly referred to in js as arrow functions. They function the same way.

That lambda equates to:

```
(function (heroes) { return _this.heroes = heroes; });
```

So it is expecting a parameter and then storing it in the local property.

The Observable in your snippet could also be written:

```
this.heroService.getHeroes()
   .subscribe((heroes: Hero[]) => {
      this.heroes = heroes;
   });
```

Which is clearer of what it is returning.

Comment: Ok, maybe I have some knowledge gap. Referring to your code: who is the heroes passaed as parameter of this function? Is it the array "returned" by the Observable when it is ready?

Comment: @AndreaNobili *"Is it the array "returned" by the Observable when it is ready?"* - that is 100% correct. Please also see my update which may be a clearer example.

Comment: So my interpreation is: the service return an  Observable<Hero[]>. When it si completed it emit the **Hero[]** array that is the heroes parameter of the function (heroes). Is it this interpretation correct?

Comment: @AndreaNobili I'm not sure if this will be at all helpful, but I made this example for a post earlier about Observables. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u36nnh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts